# Rellenar automáticamente campos del customer en stripe

Tags: drupal, stripe, drupal9

Estoy integrando stripe como plataforma de pagos de mi sistema a través de su api, y me gustaría saber cómo poder rellenar campos del customer como la dirección o el nombre automáticamente desde mi sistema. Para ser más exactos,estamos integrando un drupal con stripe y haciendo uso de sus herramientas predeterminadas, como el checkout. También me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de incluir más campos del customer para rellenar en el checkout.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Saludos

Comment: @olalla-rodicio Te recomiendo que escribas a support@stripe.com (se habla español!)